# Use of comma before the words "irregardless", "where" and after a period in time

Tags: commas, dashes, comma-splices, em-dashes

I'm unsure as to whether or not to include a comma within the two sentences outlined below (I've bolded the specific sections). In the first sentence, I have a feeling a dash might be more appropriate. Your help is most appreciated.

1. While challenging, this experience provided me with valuable insight into the strengths and needs inherent to this group and the importance of creating a community that is accessible and accommodating**,** irregardless of age or ability.
2. Using the skills I learned here, I later embarked on a position working for The Hospital of Sick Children**,** where from 2016-2017**,** I worked as a nursing aid.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't 'irregardless' an error by itself?

Comment: Yep that is an error as well. It should be regardless indeed.

Comment: @Mitch - Just like fingernails across a blackboard.

Comment: Alas, [**irregardless**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless) is an official word. However, that doesn't mean it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

In your first sentence the comma isn't needed. A straightforward way to see it is that you probably wouldn't put a comma after *accessible* if it was just that word there. Since adding another word of exactly the same type, namely *accommodating* doesn't change the structure, we also shouldn't add a comma here.

The second sentence isn't gramatically correct as it stands now, since *I*, the subject of the second part, should follow immediately after *where* as it is the subject. So a correct way to write this sentence would be *where I worked as a nursing aid from 2016-2017*. Note that this also solves the entire problem with those commas!

Comment: Hi Tyler, Thanks for clarifying. Also, thank you to those who highlighted the incorrect use of the word, "irregardless."

Comment: @GeorgeK You can just use *irrespective* instead if you're looking for a version more acceptable than *irregardless* that preserves the initial *irr-* bit if you don't go for the simpler *regardless* or some phrase like *"no matter the"* or *"without regard to"*.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I'm wondering if I need a comma in the example tyler1 proposed i.e. "Using the skills I learned here, I later embarked on a position working for The Hospital of Sick Children where I worked as a nursing aid from 2016-2017"?